# When deploying to Archiva from Jenkins is it necessary to change a settings.xml file where maven is concerned?

Tags: jenkins, archiva

I am trying to deploy from Jenkins to Archiva. I'm not very sure how it all works. I have a maven project and I have read that I need to change a settings.xml file. I cannot find such a file in my Archiva 2.0 directories.

While in Jenkins I am using the ArtifactDeployer plugin. When I try to enter the directory from which to get the artifacts there is an error saying it does not exist.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Within Jenkins, you need to register the build tools that Jenkins will use.

In regard to the buld tool Maven, I suggest:

1. Download, unzip, and install Apache Maven to the server on which Jenkins runs.
2. Configure your Maven's conf/settings.xml to point to your Archiva installation.
3. Configure the M2_HOME and PATH variables so that the mvn command can be executed.
4. Configure Jenkins to use the Apache Maven installation that you just configured.

The point is, that's a sure fire way to locate and edit a settings.xml file.

If you have Jenkins download Maven for you (I generally don't do this), then you'll have to look for a path to where Jenkins installed Maven.